# Getting NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/win32/StdCallLibrary$StdCallCallback using ghost4j in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, ghost4j

I am using ghost4j as a jar in my program to convert pdf to image. I am getting 
Exception in thread "main"

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/win32/StdCallLibrary$StdCallCallback`

I am new in using ghost4j and I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Could some one please help me with this?

Comment: Try posting some more code and the complete stacktrace which came with the exception. I haven't used ghost4, but it looks like it is looking for some Windows (win32) methods

Comment: make sure classpath is defined with all the jars you are using

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the next dependency is missing for ghost4j version 1.0.1

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

https://github.com/java-native-access/jna